# Highcharts: Is it possible to display series with the same name in different columns?

Tags: angular, highcharts

I want these obfuscated values to be displayed in different columns (5 columns). I tried disabling the grouping for plotOptions-column & series but it does not work. https://codepen.io/pearljules/pen/ExKYdzr

```
plotOptions: {
  column: {
   grouping: false
  }
},
series: [{
   name: 'People',
   data: [
     {y: 4, name: "---"},
     {y: 5, name: "---"},
     {y: 9, name: "---"},
     {y: 9, name: "---"},
     {y: 32, name: "---"}
    ]
 }]
```

[image]

Comment: Adding a minimal example in Stackblitz or Codesandbox would be appreciated.

Comment: hi. I added the codepen link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this xAxis option, the `categories` must be separated, and if you'd like the labels show `---` you can use the `format` option.

```
xAxis: {
    tickWidth: 0,
    labels: {
     format: '---',
     style: {
       color: '#fff',
       }
     },
    categories: [
      '---1', 
      '---2', 
      '---3',
      '---4',
      '---5',
    ],
    type: 'category'
}
```

https://codepen.io/ngmikeng/pen/vYGBQjm